# Swing context menu on JavaFX Chart

Tags: java, swing, javafx, charts, java-7

I am working on an application primarily in swing, though the chart dialog uses JavaFX. (`Chart` in a `GridPane` in a `JFXPanel` to be exact.)

First, `Chart` does not implement a `setContextMenu` method to use a JFX `ContextMenu`. I have seen a workaround by attaching a handler to the right click of the chart, but the menu is not removed from the GUI when it loses focus, rather it persists until the user either 1) triggers it to open again or 2) clicks a `MenuItem`.

```
chart.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        if (t.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            contextMenu.show(chart, t.getScreenX(), t.getScreenY());
        }
    }
});
```

That said, I would prefer to use a Swing `JPopupMenu` instead. How can I bind this to my `Chart` and maintain a natural behavior?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined it was not possible to use a `JPopupMenu`.

The `ContextMenu` is added to a `JLabel`:

```
Label contextMenuLabel = new Label();
grid.add(contextMenuLabel, 0, 0); // Add to the same grid after adding the chart
contextMenuLabel.setPrefSize(width, height);
contextMenuLabel.setMinSize(width, height);
contextMenuLabel.setMaxSize(width, height);

ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

contextMenuLabel.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
```